# I2C Raspberry Pi to PIC24F

Tags: pic, i2c, raspberry-pi

I'm new to PIC's and PIC programming but I'm working on a little project to try get a PIC24F32KA301 to communicate with a Raspberry Pi using I2C. The Raspberry Pi is the master and the PIC is the slave. I have created a little Python program on the Raspberry Pi and tested that it works by successfully communicating with an Arduino, what I want to do now is replace the Arduino with a PIC.

Just for completeness I've included the python program below:

```
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x22

def writeNumber(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    return -1

def readNumber():
    number = bus.read_byte(address)
    return number

while True:
    var = input("Enter 1 - 9: ")
    if not var:
        continue
    writeNumber(var)
    print "RPI: Hi Arduino, I sent you ", var

    time.sleep(1)
    number = readNumber()
    print "Arduino: Hey RPI, I received a digit ", number
    print
```

I'm pretty sure I've connected the PIC and Raspberry Pi correctly:

GND <---> Vss (pin 19)
SCL <---> SCL1 (pin 12)
SDA <---> SDA1 (pin 13)

The Raspberry Pi is powered over USB (I think it's 5V, but it might be 3V) and the PIC is powered separately using a 3V battery. The Arduino didn't have any pull up resistors so I assume it's ok to not have any on the PIC (maybe this is wrong?).

I'm using C with the XC16 compiler and the i2c.h library to program the PIC but I'm not really sure what I'm doing, I've tried my best to piece things together from I2C examples and little bits I've read on various forums etc:

```
#define USE_AND_OR    // not sure what this is!
#include <p24Fxxxx.h>
#include <i2c.h>

unsigned char I2C_RECV[1]

void main(void) {
    unsigned int temp, i;
    for(i=0; i<1; i++)
        I2C_RECV[i]=0;

    TRISA = 0b0000000000000000;
    PORTA = 0b0000000000000001;

    /* INITIALISE I2C MODULE  */
    CloseI2C1();                            // close i2c if it was operating earlier

    while(1) {
        OpenI2C1((I2C_ON | I2C_7BIT_ADD | I2C_CLK_REL | I2C_STR_EN), 0);
        I2C1ADD = 0x22;                     // initialze slave address to 1E

        // receive data from master
        while(DataRdyI2C1() == 0);          // wait until data is transmitted from master
        temp = SlaveReadI2C1();             // read address to empty buffer

        SlavegetsI2C1(I2C_RECV, 1);         // receive data

        if(I2C_RECV[0] == 9) {
            PORTA = 0b0000000000000011;
        }

        CloseI2C1();
    }
}
```

The code is quite simple (but probably wrong!). Basically I initialise the I2C module and turn on an LED, then I enter a loop, open the I2C connection using address 0x22 and wait for the master to send some data. When data is received I check it's value, if it's 9 I turn on another LED.

On the Raspberry Pi I can confirm that the PIC is accessible by running `i2cdetect -y 1`. I can see the PIC at address 0x22, which gives me some confidence that I'm at least heading in the right direction! However, when I run the python program I receive an IO error, the error number is 5. I've looked around to find out what that means, but it's a very vague error, basically anything could have gone wrong!

I'm not sure if it's my circuit that's incorrect (i.e. do I need pull up resistors, if so how do I calculate what resistance they need to be?) or my PIC program. If anyone can check the program makes sense or has any advice I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: As you noticed the RPI has 1.8k pullups integrated, so you should not need to add any

Comment: Why are you reopening the I2C and reinitializing the address in your while loop?  Shouldn't that happen outside the loop?

Answer (score -2):

Test this:

```
unsigned char I2C_RECV[1]

void main(void) {
  unsigned int temp=0,temp2=0, i;
  for(i=0; i<1; i++)
     I2C_RECV[i]=0;

  TRISA = 0b0000000000000000;
  PORTA = 0b0000000000000001;

  /* INITIALISE I2C MODULE  */
  CloseI2C1();        // close i2c if it was operating earlier

  while(1){

   config1 = (I2C_ON | I2C_7BIT_ADD | I2C_CLK_REL | I2C_STR_EN  );
   config2 = 0;                //This defines I2C to be slave
   OpenI2C1(config1,config2);  //configure I2C1
   I2C1ADD = 0x22;             //I2C address set to 1E  

    I2C1CONbits.I2CEN = 1;     // ENABLE I2C!!
    I2C1CONbits.DISSLW = 1;    // Disable slew rate control
    I2C1CONbits.GCEN = 1;      // Enable interrupt when a general call address is received (enable for reception)

    while(IFS1bits.SI2C1IF==0){asm ("clrwdt");}; //wait untill the data is transmitted from master

    temp = SlaveReadI2C1();     //Read address to empty buffer
    temp2 = SlaveReadI2C1();    //Read data to empty buffer

    SlavegetsI2C1(I2C_RECV,1);

    if(temp2 == 0x09) PORTA = 0b0000000000000011;
    else PORTA = 0b0000000000000000;        
    CloseI2C1();      //Disable I2C
  }  
}
```

Comment: You should include some additional information and not just paste code.

Comment: Rev1.0 is right: maybe you could highlight the changes from the previous code, explaining how they make it work.